# Nesting Wait-Event cmdlets in PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to solve a problem that involves detecting a dynamically created directory by another software, of which this directory also has dynamically generated files of which I want to monitor.

I have come up with the following PowerShell script, but there is a problem. The first event works fine, and detects the new directory added. However, when I subscribe to another, nested event to watch the just-made directory, I can't ever seem to get the event to fire. I have debugged and verified that the second event does indeed get registered, and verified via `Get-EventSubscriber`. My breakpoints in the method `dir2Watcher_OnCreated` never get hit, and it seems like the event is never caught. The event watchers in both cases are practically identical (I've removed filtering for now for simplicity), yet the issue persists. I thought that it might be due to a synchronicity issue, but it seems like when `Wait-Event` cmdlets are called, it waits synchronously. I could be wrong, but I couldn't find any information on multi-threading with PowerShell regarding events.

Additionally, I was able to successfully replicate a similar logic in C#, which **does** work. Both examples of the code are below. I would like to replicate this logic in PowerShell, if capable. Any advice as to why the second event in PowerShell isn't firing would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Addition information:

Get-Host (output during a debug session)
[image: Get-Host output during a debug session]

PowerShell:

```
$dir1Watcher = New-Object -TypeName "System.IO.FileSystemWatcher" -ArgumentList @("C:\test") -Property @{"EnableRaisingEvents" = $true}

function dir1Watcher_OnCreated ([Object] $sender, [System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs] $e) {
    
    Write-Host $e.FullPath

    $dir2Watcher = New-Object -TypeName "System.IO.FileSystemWatcher" -ArgumentList @($e.FullPath) -Property @{"EnableRaisingEvents" = $true}

    if ($null -ne (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated")) {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated"
    }
    if ($null -ne (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "dir2WatcherOnCreated")) {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir2WatcherOnCreated"
    }

    try {
    
        Register-ObjectEvent $dir2Watcher -EventName "Created" -SourceIdentifier "dir2WatcherOnCreated" -Action {dir2Watcher_OnCreated $Sender $EventArgs}
        Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir2WatcherOnCreated"
    
    }
    catch { throw }
    finally {
        if ($null -ne (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "dir2WatcherOnCreated")) {
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir2WatcherOnCreated"
        }
        if ($null -ne $dir2Watcher) { $dir2Watcher.Dispose() }
    }

}

function dir2Watcher_OnCreated ([Object] $sender, [System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs] $e) {   
    Write-Host $e.FullPath
}


if ($null -ne (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated")) {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated"
}

try {

    Register-ObjectEvent $dir1Watcher -EventName "Created" -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated" -Action {dir1Watcher_OnCreated $Sender $EventArgs}
    Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated"

}
catch { throw }
finally {
    if ($null -ne (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated")) {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "dir1WatcherOnCreated"
    }
    if ($null -ne $dir1Watcher) { $dir1Watcher.Dispose() }
}
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace DirectoryWatcher
{
    class Program { 

        public static ManualResetEvent _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _quitEvent.Set();
                e.Cancel = true;
            };

            Watcher w = new Watcher();
            _quitEvent.WaitOne();

        }
    }

    class Watcher
    {

        FileSystemWatcher dir1Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\test") { EnableRaisingEvents = true };
        FileSystemEventHandler dir1WatcherHandler;

        public Watcher()
        {
            dir1WatcherHandler = new FileSystemEventHandler(dir1Watcher_OnCreated);
            dir1Watcher.Created += dir1WatcherHandler;
        }

        void dir1Watcher_OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);

            FileSystemWatcher dir2Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(e.FullPath) { EnableRaisingEvents = true };
            FileSystemEventHandler dir2WatcherHandler = new FileSystemEventHandler(dir2Watcher_OnCreated);

            dir1Watcher.Created -= dir1WatcherHandler;
            dir2Watcher.Created += dir2WatcherHandler;

        }

        void dir2Watcher_OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you get an exception in the finally in the Power Shell?

Comment: It would probably go unhandled. This is just a quick mockup. In my testing, I haven't seen any exceptions occur in those finally blocks.

Comment: I think that is where the issue is.  Yes they go unhandled but the lines of code do not execute.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the suggestion. However I ended up commenting out the finally blocks in both cases, and the issue still persists.

Comment: Commenting out the finally blocks proves nothing.  You still don't know if the issue is before the finally block or in the finally block.  The only way of proving if the issue is in the finally block is to add another try/catch in the finally block.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and added another try/catch block in the finally blocks. Nothing has changed. Keep in mind, I am using a debugger to step through the flow of code. I am 100% confident those finally blocks are unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Only difference I see between the c# and PowerShell is the PowerShell is unregistering two events while c# is on unregistering one.

Comment: The power shell only does that because during my testing, sometimes after starting a new debug session, those event subscribers would remain. That's just an extra precaution to guarantee that each time the event is made, it's the only one.

Comment: The C# uses some background multithreading to achieve that logic slightly differently, where-as I think the PowerShell scripts are exclusive to waiting for events synchronously, so I know this is at least a fundamental difference. I removed the reference to the first event hoping it would clear up any lock that might prevent the second event from firing, but that didn't help. I'm wondering if I have to close some .NET background thread keeping that first event watcher alive or something, but this is just a guess.